# Mysql BIgQuery to one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, select, join

I had create tables with one to many relationship , size of rows `11328441`.
The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `gameresnum` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DRAWDAY` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DRAWNO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DRAWTIME` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `RESNUM` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `gameresnum`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `RESNUM` (`RESNUM`);
```

.

I tried to make this query :

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM gameresnum gone
JOIN gameresnum gtwo ON gone.DRAWNO=gtwo.DRAWNO WHERE gone.RESNUM=1 AND gtwo.RESNUM=2
```

But it is very slow up to 2 mint.

Comment: Please give it a try: `SELECT count(*) as count FROM gameresnum gone
JOIN gameresnum gtwo ON gone.DRAWNO=gtwo.DRAWNO AND gone.ID < gtwo.ID WHERE gone.RESNUM=1 AND gtwo.RESNUM=2`

Comment: i edit my question thanks.

Comment: And I edited my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would benefit from

```
INDEX(resnum, drawno) -- composite and covering
```

You could also experiment with

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT 1
            FROM gamesresnum
            WHERE resnum IN (1, 2)
            GROUP BY drawno
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  -- to see if both are present
         ) AS x
```

It needs `INDEX(drawno, resnum)`.

Caveat:  This reformulation assumes that `(drawno, resnum)` is unique.  I don't know if this will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

your drawno column does not have an index. thats why.

Comment: Note that a composite index `(drawno, resnum)` would be even better.